# wildfly: reading properties file from classpath directory

Tags: java, url, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to read deployment specific information from a properties file in my claspath folder. War file is deployed on wildfly 13 via domain mode.

/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/APPS1/tmp/vfs/temp/tempe22b1a59c629344/content-35e1234535af2e86/WEB-INF/classes/bis/com/test/config/application.properties

When i try to get my path using the following

```
System.getProperty(jboss.server.temp.dir)
```

I only get /opt/wildfly/domain/servers/APPS1/tmp

I am running this code from this class bis.com.test.module.app

bis|com|test|module|app.class

bis|com|test|config|application.properties

I have tried

```
private static final String PATH = "/WEB-INF/classes/bis/com/test/config/application.properties";

Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
props.load(in);
String JDBC = props.getProperty("jdbc.connection");

Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream in = App.class().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
props.load(in);
String JDBC = props.getProperty("jdbc.connection");

Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH);
props.load(in);
String JDBC = props.getProperty("jdbc.connection");

URL url = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource(PATH);
Properties app = new Properties();
           app.load(url.openStream());
String JDBC = app.getProperty("jdbc.connection");
```

However im getting null pointer exception for all...how do i bypass/access/retrieve the temp folders and go into the WEB-INF folders? Im unable to move the application properties elsewhere due to current design logic. I only can access the properties file here. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found that your `application.properties` reside under a package so it should be accessed as given below:

```
ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/bis/com/test/config/application.properties");
```

Comment: What does this give to you `jboss.server.config.dir` or `jboss.domain.config.dir` in path ?

Comment: I think you must explore all the variables given in the docs once, it might happen that one of the variable gives you exact path or near to the constant one, found `jboss.domain.temp.dir` also in `https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Admin_Guide.html`

Comment: I have a feeling, we are thinking in wrong direction :)

Comment: Yes, the closest one is from `jboss.server.temp.dir` where ill get `opt/wildfly/domain/servers/APPS1/tmp` however im unable to access `/vfs/temp/tempe22b1a59c629344/content-35e1234535af2e86` this portion of the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221726/discussion-between-code-mechanic-and-roth).